# Given any function $g(x): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, find a function $f(x)$ such that $f(f(x)) = g(x)$.

Tags: analysis

This is a problem I was casually discussing with friends:

> Given any function $g(x): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, find a
>   function $f(x): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(f(x)) = g(x)$.

Is it possible to find a solution for $f(x)$ or prove that there isn't a solution for $f(x)$ such that $f(f(x)) = g(x)$ for any given $g(x)$?

For example, if $g(x) = x + 2$, then $f(x)$ could easily be $f(x) = x + 1$. But if $g(x) = x^2 - 1$, then it's not clear to see what $f$ can satisfy such solution.

What approach might be promising? My first gut reaction would be some analytical method but can't think of a way still...Discussions are welcomed!

Comment: Square roots rarely "always exist", why do you expect it to hold for composition on the set of one dimensional real functions of one real variable?

Comment: Thanks @GitGud! I don't expect the square to exist. If it doesn't exist, I would like to see a way to systematically see. I was thinking whether I can view this as operators and their squares over one dimensional space and find the square root. Then we have similarity to positive semidefinite operators which will always have square.

Comment: Related MO question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17614/solving-ffx-gx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for the [functional square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_square_root) of $g(x)$. In most cases it does exist, but the solutions are mind-bogglingly complicated. See the Wikipedia article for more information.

Comment: And [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_square_root) is the link for non-mobile users.

Comment: Hm... I'm on the app, and I copy-pasted from mobile Firefox without removing the m! What a zit.

Comment: Thank you! The Schröder's method answers my questions about higher-order square roots as well.

Comment: @celtschk It's fixed, thank you.

Comment: Is there an explicit example of a function $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  with no square root?  Or a class of functions where they are guaranteed to exist, like analytic functions perhaps?

Comment: @JairTaylor First, I had been almost convinced that $x\mapsto -x$ did not have a functional square root on the real line, but then, to my surprise, found one (see my answer below). It would be very interesting to see a function without one, indeed.

Comment: @triple_sec Actually it's very easy to come up with a functional square root for $x \mapsto x$... :) I assume you mean $x \mapsto -x$.

Comment: @JairTaylor Edited, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is not intended to be a full answer, more like a thought experiment that is too long for a comment.

As @ParclyTaxel mentioned, functional square roots abound, but sometimes they are very difficult to find. Let me expand on this point via a simple example.

Consider the function $g:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ defined on the whole complex plane as $g(x)\equiv -x$ for each $x\in\mathbb C$. It is very easy to find a function $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ such that $f\circ f=g$; define $f(x)\equiv\mathsf ix$ for each $x\in\mathbb C$.

However, what if $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, still defined as $g(x)\equiv -x$ for $x\in\mathbb R$, is restricted to the real line? A solution to the functional-square-root problem still exists, but the answer is way less obvious in this case.

To exhibit one such solution, first note that the intervals $(0,1)$ and $[1,\infty)$ have the same cardinality, so that there exists a bijection $h:(0,1)\to[1,\infty)$ between them. Denote the inverse as $h^{-1}:[1,\infty)\to(0,1)$. Define $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
f(x)\equiv\begin{cases}h^{-1}(-x)&\text{if $x\in(-\infty,-1]$},\\-h(-x)&\text{if $x\in(-1,0)$,}\\0&\text{if $x=0$,}\\h(x)&\text{if $x\in(0,1)$,}\\-h^{-1}(x)&\text{if $x\in[1,\infty)$.}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
It is not difficult to check that $f\circ f=g$, but, as you can see, the answer is less straightforward than it was in the complex case.

Comment: Nice thought experiment! Thanks!